# Epiphany internal PDF viewer just flickers

Tags: release-hera, applications, epiphany, bugs

When viewing PDFs in Epiphany's internal viewer the PDF is basically unreadable due to heavy flickering.

Is there a workaround to open PDFs externally until fixed?

Answer (score 0):

There is a button you can use to download it, but the button is part of the internal PDF viewer, so I assume you're unable to use it.

I can guarantee this won't be fixed because nobody has reported a bug. First step would be a bug report on gitlab.gnome.org.